# Where can we use "This" in Recursion method

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have a method in a static class which tries to convert a binary tree to a list

I'd like to make it recursive but I couldn't

I've implemented some other methods in my class like `add()`, `delete()`, `find()`.

Here is the code

```
class ARB
{
        private:
                struct BT
                {
                        int data;
                        BT *l;
                        BT *r;
                };
                struct BT *p;
       public
                ARB();
                ~ARB();
                void del(int n);
                void add(int n); 
};

    void ARB::del(int num)
{
//The code ,don't care about it 

  };  

main()
{
// 
    BTR T;
    T.add(3);
    T.add(5);

};
```

Here is what should we do to transfer the code from binary tree to list.

```
LLC ARB::changeit()
{   LLC x;
        while(this!=NULL)
        {
            x.add(this->data); //
                if(this.l==NULL)
                {
                       x.print(); //To print the elemnts of List
                        return(x);
                }
                else
                {
                        x=changeit(this.l);
                }

                if(this.r!=NULL)
                {
                       x.~LLC();
                       x=changeit(this.r);
                        return(x);
                }

        }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Where are you getting errors? Which errors?

Comment: The program wasn't compiled ,There is prob in the code but I couldn't find it

Comment: It seems the OP wants to convert a binary tree to a list by using recursion and doesn't know how. Although the question seems unrelated to the actual problem. There seems to be quite a few conceptual issues to solve before being able to help him. google (or search - if you are in China).

Answer (score 0):

The description of the problem is hard to follow but I noticed that you used the keywords `this` and `static`, which are generally mutually exclusive.

Any `static` function pertains to a class, not an object. Static functions can be called using the `ARB::myStaticFunction()` syntax and do not require an actual `ARB` object. So, `this` inside such a function does not refer to any object and is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

This call is meaningless:

```
x=changeit(this.l);
```

Since `this` refers to the `ARB` object that has no member called `l`. The same goes for this code:

```
this->data
```

You sometimes do `this.data` and sometimes `this->data` so you seem to be confused over the notion of an object pointer. Your `ARB` has the `BT*` called `p` which is the tree root, supposedly. You should start from it.

Also this is obviosly wrong:

```
x.~LLC();
```

Don't call the destructor of `LLC` explicitly!

The general algorithm for recursively placing a binary tree into a list (pseudocode):

```
tolist(node, list):
  if node == NULL:
    return
  else:
    tolist(node.left, list)
    list.append_to_end(node.data)
    tolist(node.right)
```

This assumes `append_to_end` of list is efficient, to make sense (this is achievable with an end pointer in the list). Also, it takes a list as an argument and modifies it. You can easily change it to have an internal recursive method that does that and an external method that creates a list, calls this method, and returns the list.